# Is there a verse in the Vedas that confirms the existence of the Para-brahaman in materialistic form?

Tags: vedas

I'm looking for a source from the **Vedas** and not from *Purana* and *Upanishads* about confirmation of the existence of Para-brahman in Materialistic form.

Comment: Quite the opposite. The Upanishads give the sequence of creation from Parabrahman. Gross Materials are at the end and are a combination of the fine elements.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Please mention the verses with translation and name of upanishads as well.

Comment: If we view the concept of of **brahman** in pure Spiritual sense, then we can say "Yes, there is confirmation of Existence of Para-brahman in Materialistic form"

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Nope, I do need verses with translation from Vedas nd Purans both.

Comment: @MIKEYSINGH - In your question you want verses from Vedas and not from puranas or Upanishads. But you are saying in your above comment that you need from both.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Basically, i need it from vedas as per i have seen already many from purans. In above comment my aim was just to get both verses from Ved and Puran as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have to understand the core of SPIRITUALITY  carefully.

[Mundaka upanishad 3.2.9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145141.html) says as follows:

> स यो ह वै तत् परमं ब्रह्म वेद ब्रह्मैव भवति नास्याब्रह्मवित्कुले भवति
> । तरति शोकं तरति पाप्मानं गुहाग्रन्थिभ्यो विमुक्तोऽमृतो भवति ॥ ९ ॥
>
> sa yo ha vai tat paramaṃ brahma veda brahmaiva bhavati
> nāsyābrahmavitkule bhavati | tarati śokaṃ tarati pāpmānaṃ
> guhāgranthibhyo vimukto'mṛto bhavati || 9 ||
>
> ***He who knows that highest Brahman becomes even Brahman***; and in his line, none who knows not the Brahman will be born. He crosses
> grief and virtue and vice and being freed from the knot of the heart,
> becomes immortal.

---

So one who REALISES, but not understands, BRAHMAN becomes BRAHMAN.

Sages like Vamadeva, Viswamitra, Vasistha, etc, in that era, and Sages like Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Sri Ramana Maharshi, etc, of our era REALISED the BRAHMAN and thus they are BRAHMAN by themselves.

This is existence of Para-brahman in Materialistic/Human form.

---

Coming to the issue of reference to the Veda, where such mention was made, we can refer to [Rig Veda IV.26.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv04026.htm)  The rishi is ***Vāmadeva Gautama***

What did he say?

> अहम मनुर अभवं सूर्यश चाहं कक्षीवां रषिर अस्मि विप्रः | अहं कुत्सम
> आर्जुनेयं नय ॠञ्जे ऽहं कविर उशना पश्यता मा || अहम भूमिम अददाम
> आर्यायाहं वर्ष्टिं दाशुषे मर्त्याय | अहम अपो अनयं वावशाना मम देवासो
> अनु केतम आयन || अहम पुरो मन्दसानो वय ऐरं नव साकं नवतीः शम्बरस्य |
> शततमं वेश्यं सर्वताता दिवोदासम अतिथिग्वं यद आवम ||
>
> 1. I became Manu and the sun. I am Kakṣīvant, the inspired seer. I steered myself down to Kutsa, the son of Arjuna. I am Kavi Uśanā. Look
>    at me!
> 2. I gave land to the Ārya; I (gave) rain to the pious mortal. I led the bellowing waters. It is my will that the gods followed.
> 3. I, in my exhilaration, broke apart all at once the nine and ninety fortresses of Śambara, and the hundredth, his dwelling place, to
>    complete it, when I helped Divodāsa Atithigva

---

Why did Vāmadeva Gautama say that

- I became Manu and the sun?
- I gave land to the Ārya; I (gave) rain to the pious mortal?
- I, in my exhilaration, broke apart all at once the nine and ninety fortresses of Śambara?

---

It is because Vāmadeva Gautama became the BRAHMAN and thus he was speaking as if HE did it all.

***This is existence of Para-brahman in Materialistic/Human form.***

However, we should not expect the BRAHMAN to take form of the Gods that we are accustomed to , ie., Vishnu, Shiva, Devi, Ganapati, etc, and live among us.