# Are the Realized Guru and Jivanmukta omnipresent?

Tags: guru

We know that he is not omniscient in the sense of knowing everything simultaneously, only that he has access to all knowledge when he wants it, at least according to Hariharananda Baba. So how is he then omnipresent; how does he know he is omnipresent if he only perceives something from one location? And what about the jivanmukta? Is he omnipresent as well?

Comment: Omniscience,Omnipotence & Omnipresent are properties of infinite Brahman or Atman, not of finite jivatma.A yogi is called realized guru or jivanmukta, they are not two different states,but different terminologies just like Brahman of Vedas is same as Atman of Yoga is same as God of bhakti yoga.what is Yogi? One who is connected to Atman or Brahman which is omnipresent & omniscient & contain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records .For e.g., today's educated person with phone & google can search anything, hackers can hack the net, but century back or illiterate had access to no such thing

Comment: If the Guru is realized, He knows he is not the body but the infinite Self. Ramana Maharishi used to ask "where am I not?" whenever devotees shed tears knowing he'd leave his body soon.  "They say that I am dying, but I am not going away. Where could I go? I am here."  -'Ramana Maharshi and the Path of Self-knowledge' p. 222.

Answer (score 1):

[Kena Upanisahd` 1.5-8](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad/d/doc122448.html) say, on **OMNIPRESENCE** of Brahman,  as follows:

> - What speech cannot reveal, but what reveals speech—know thou **That alone as Brahman**, and not this (anything objective)that people
>   worship here
> - What mind does not comprehend, but what comprehends the mind— know thou **That alone as Brahman**, and not this that people worship here
> - What hearing fails to hear, but what hears hearing— know thou ***That alone as Brahman***, and not this that people worship here
> - What smell does not reveal, but what reveals smell— know thou ***That alone as Brahman***, and not this that people worship here

---

[Mundaka upanishad 3.2.9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad/d/doc122448.html) says as follows:

> स यो ह वै तत् परमं ब्रह्म वेद ब्रह्मैव भवति नास्याब्रह्मवित्कुले भवति
> । तरति शोकं तरति पाप्मानं गुहाग्रन्थिभ्यो विमुक्तोऽमृतो भवति ॥ ९ ॥
>
> sa yo ha vai tat paramaṃ brahma veda brahmaiva bhavati
> nāsyābrahmavitkule bhavati | tarati śokaṃ tarati pāpmānaṃ
> guhāgranthibhyo vimukto'mṛto bhavati || 9 ||
>
> ***He who knows that highest Brahman becomes even Brahman***; and in his line, none who knows not the Brahman will be born. He crosses
> grief and virtue and vice and being freed from the knot of the heart,
> becomes immortal.

---

Coming to the aspects of Guru and Jivanmukta, we have to understand that a Jivanmukta is the one, who got SELF REALISATION or REALISED the BRAHMAN, while living in the present body.

Hence, as per Mundaka upanishad 3.2.9  - ***He who knows that highest Brahman becomes even Brahman***, a Jivanmukta is a BRAHMAN, and thus he is OMNIPRESENT.

***[Sage Vāmadeva Gautama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42342/3869) is one such Jivanmukta.***

And, a Jivanmukta may be a Guru or may not be a Guru, depending upon the prArabdha of the body that Jivanmukta is in.

Some Jivanmuktas may complete their life time, without being noticed by anyone as such or without guiding any disciples.

---